# Usage Data via Valence API

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a way to pull user usage data from the Valence API?

In particular I want to know if a user has ever logged in or accessed a certain course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, currently that information is not available through the Valence APIs. If you'd like the Valence APIs to provide that information, and you're affiliated with a D2L customer, please use their account management chain to report your request. If you're not directly affiliated with a D2L account manager, then you can report your request through the [Valence support chain](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/about.html#support).

This particular request is something that other partners and customers have indicated an interest for.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've submitted a feature request.